# Optimal Caching - "Farthest in Future" Algorithm

Tags: python, performance

I'm looking for someone to really tear apart the following code I wrote for my graduate-level algorithms class. The problem was Optimal Caching, and the algorithm I'm implementing is called "Farthest in Future", which looks to see which cache item is either NOT in the request, or one who's first occurrence appears LAST compared to the other items.

I'm looking for ways to get the run-time down. Right now I think it's O(n+k), with n being the length of requests and k being the length of the cache, after the initial data structure (the indices dict) is created. Please let me know if I'm wrong! I'm still learning!

Also looking how I can better organize my code like this in the future.

```
cache = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
requests = ['e', 'f', 'c', 'g']

def get_items(cache, queue):

  # Handles cache "hits"
  def cache_hit(item):
    print('HIT', cache)
    return item

  def cache_miss(item):
    # evict "farthest in future" item
    fif = get_farthest_in_future(cache, queue)
    cache.remove(fif)
    cache.append(item)
    print('MISS', cache)

  # Predicts which item occurs "farthest in the future"
  def get_farthest_in_future(cache, requests):
    max_index = 0
    for cache_item in cache:
      # next appearance
      if len(indices[cache_item]) > 0:
        next_appearance = indices[cache_item][0]
        if next_appearance > max_index:
          max_index = next_appearance
          fif = requests[max_index]
          break
      else:
        fif = cache_item
        break
    return fif

  #### CREATE DATA STRUCTURES #####
  def get_indices(cache, queue):
    indices = {}

    # ensure that every cache item 
    # has an entry in the dict
    for cache_item in cache:
      indices[cache_item] = []

    for i, item in enumerate(queue):
      if item not in indices:
        indices[item] = [i]
      else:
        indices[item].append(i)

    return indices
  
  indices = get_indices(cache, queue)
  
  for item in queue:

    print('request:', item)

    # update indices
    indices[item].pop(0)

    if item in cache:
      cache_hit(item)
    else: 
      cache_miss(item)

get_items(cache, requests)
```

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: @StefanPochmann If I understand it correctly: see if the requested value is at the head of the cache. If it isn't, add the requested value to the tail of the cache. But I'm not 100% sure on that, so clarification is welcome.

Comment: @Mast Nah I don't mean how to achieve the goal, but *what is* the goal? Is it the modified `cache`? Is it the `print` outputs? And what are these for the given example data?

Comment: The code presented does *not* implement *evict Farthest in Future*. `get_farthest_in_future()` seems broken. How did you test? I tried `cache = [None, None]
get_items(cache, [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1])`